# How to prevent two events from firing simultaneously in extjs

Tags: select, extjs, onitemclick

My grid has check box selection model. on item click i have some logic to do. But when i select check box it firing select and item click event. How do i prevent item click event on check box selection.I am using ExtJS 4.1

Thanks

Comment: and why do you have checkbox selection model?

Answer (score 0):

We need checkbox selection since on 'checking' of multiple items we let the user click a button and change some value. At the same time if they click anywhere else on the record in gridpanel they get to view a detailed view.

I took care of this as follows. When constructing the gridPanel I set the config property 'checkonly' as true. This would mean that the check box gets checked only when you click on the column containing the checkbox and not any where else on that record or row on the grid panel. After that i changed the controller to listen to a cellclick event instead of doubleclick. The controller does not do anything if the cell that generated the cellclick event has an index of 0 which is the checbox cell. If the user clicks on any other column or cell in the row on the gridpanel then the controller initiates the detailed view.